# Idiom for "doing something pleasant and useful at the same time" with positive connotation

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a phraseme or idiom for "doing something useful (necessary) and pleasant at the same time" with positive connotation?

For example - using a bike to get to work and back home is useful (because it allows you to train your body), and pleasant (if you go through the park or a forest, etc.).

Or, another possible example - a boss may convince an employee to sign in for a business trip (to the North Pole) because it is useful to the firm and may be pleasant because the employee is an amateur photographer and will have a chance to take a photo of a polar bear.

There is a Russian phraseme that is usable in both cases, but is there a similar one in English for at least one of the cases?

Comment: There are many non-idiomatic phrases, such as *delightful task* and *pleasant chore*. Why do you need an idiom?

Comment: @bib Maybe the phrase will do, but "delightful task" doesn't have a "it may seem boring at first glance, but in fact there is a pleasant side".

Comment: In US usage, the terms *task* and *chore* both have a slightly negative connotation when used alone.

Comment: And then there's the phrase from John Mellencamp, *Hurts so good*.

Comment: @bib *Hurts so good* - very nice! :)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, but the the phrase "whistle while you work" comes to mind.  It doesn't quite answer the question because it denotes that the person doing the work must proactively make the work pleasant, when it normally would not appeal to the person at all.

Comment: How about `"mixing business with pleasure"`?

Comment: @Marc Actually this phrase has the same structure that Russian one, but it has negative connotation. And this "mixing" part has the idea of forcing two different things to be one in some artificial way.

Comment: In Czech (and in many other Slavic languages, it appears) there is a phrase like “to combine pleasant with useful” (“spojit příjemné s užitečným”). The circumstances (tax reasons, inheritance, whatever) rushed him to ask her to marry him. He was very glad to do it, and he used the opportunity which forced him to finally act. It is completely serious, non-ironical statement. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

> It's a tough job, but somebody has to do it.

I'd suggest that it's used ironically far more often than literally.